# Where have I gone wrong? (Series evalution)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know how to write notation on text so I'll put a picture.
The top line is definitely right, but the conclusion is definitely wrong, so where have I gone wrong in the middle?

[image: updated pic]

Comment: $\frac{1}{1^2+1}$ is outside the sum.

Comment: yeah it is, sorry I should've put brackets over the sum

Comment: updated the pic

Comment: The fact that a + b = c + d does not imply that (a,b) = (c,d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're complicating this series with the $2^n$. $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right)=1$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't really explain properly. I already know what the series converges to. What I want to know is how I got to the conclusion of the last expression (which is clearly not equivalent) and where I went wrong.

Comment: Where is the $\sum$ in the last line?

Comment: I'm comparing the RHS of the first line to the RHS of the second last line, that's how I obtained the last line. Are you not allowed to do that?

Comment: $\sum a_n=\sum b_n\not\Longrightarrow a_n=b_n$.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong because of $\frac1{1+1}$ first term, not in all term.

$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. You partial sum to this telescoping series then take limit.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get what you meant in the first sentence.

Comment: Also if I use the separated partial fractions I have to sum 1/n which doesn't converge

Comment: you cant seperate if there is minus between them.

Comment: Ok nevermind that, which line have I gone wrong though? What's wrong with taking out the 1/(1+1) term